# SQL: Adding column totals as part of case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing an insert query where I am inserting data from one table to another, and due to the nature of the table, I have to pivot them but I need to get totals as well.

Table 1 Fields:

| date | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 | cat_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 5 |

Table 2 fields:

| date | cat_type | cat_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-04 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-04 | 3 | 2 |

I need to get the values of table 2 into table 1

Below is the query I am trying

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (File_date, cat_1, cat_2, cat_3, cat_total)  
  SELECT File_date
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 1 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_1
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 2 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_2
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 3 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_3
        , (cat_1 + cat_2 + cat_3) as cat_total
     FROM Table2
 GROUP BY File_date
```

but I am getting an error saying cat_1 is not found

Comment: You can't access the aliases to make `cat_total`. You'll have to do something like `CASE WHEN cat_type IN (1, 2, 3) THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END` or if it's nullable you could do an update after the `INSERT`.

Comment: thank you Derrick. I was thinking the same. But if I do an update, how will I cant use the where clause? I dont have a way of identifying the rows? For eg: update set cat_total = (cat_1 +cat_2 +cat_3) where unique condition?

Comment: You don't need a `WHERE` statement if you want to update all the rows.

Comment: went with the update after the insert as suggested. Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

something like this.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (File_date, cat_1, cat_2, cat_3, cat_total)  
      SELECT File_date
            , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 1 THEN cat_count ELSE 0 END) AS cat_1
            , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 2 THEN cat_count ELSE 0 END) AS cat_2
            , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 3 THEN cat_count ELSE 0 END) AS cat_3
            , SUM(cat_count) as cat_total
         FROM Table2
    WHERE cat_type IN (1,2,3)
     GROUP BY File_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias like this but you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (File_date, cat_1, cat_2, cat_3, cat_total)  
  SELECT File_date
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 1 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_1
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 2 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_2
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 3 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_3
        , SUM((CASE WHEN cat_type = 1 THEN cat_count ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN cat_type = 2 THEN cat_count ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN cat_type = 3 THEN cat_count ELSE 0 END)) as cat_total
     FROM Table2
 GROUP BY File_date
```